# Using PersistentAuditEvent in JHipster for managing custom events

Tags: jhipster, audit

I notice that JHipster microservices have their own `Auditing` viz. `PersistentAuditEvent` it seems easier to use than say `AuditEventRepository` which only has `add` and some limited `find` methods.

I want to save an `Event` of a task being run with a role of `SYSTEM` and identify it by something like `type:executedLongQuery`
Then in future I want to check the last run of this query and decide whether we need to run in again for report generation then log an event again if it is run. It seems to me PersistentAuditEvent offered by JHipster is the best way to go.

I don't see a `PersistentAuditEventRepository` or any suitable implementation within the microservice so if I can get a documentation with example that would be very helpful. Even a clue in the right direction could help me start.

Comment: I found the repository interface and a custom implementation in gateway. Is it safe to simply copy over that code and edit the code? Would it in any way break compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the repository interface and a custom implementation in JHipster Gateway which is not present in microservice. It was easy to simply copy it over to microservice and use the repository. Ofcourse here I am using a database in the microservice, an empty one, which still adds the migrations as well as Audit tables.